# replacing values in 2d arrays in c

Tags: c

I have searched through this site and found some very helpful information up to this point but I struggle in rewriting elements in arrays or finding info on this site on how to go about doing it. This is the part of the code I'm stuck on.

```
int game_board[3][3];
int row, col, i = 1;
for (row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    for (col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        game_board[row][col] = i++;

for (row = 0; row < 3; row++)
{
    for (col = 0; col < 3; col++)

        printf("%d\t", game_board[row][col]);
    printf("\n");
}
int spot1 = game_board[0][0];
int spot2 = game_board[0][1];
int spot3 = game_board[0][2];
int spot4 = game_board[1][0];
int spot5 = game_board[1][1];
int spot6 = game_board[1][2];
int spot7 = game_board[2][0];
int spot8 = game_board[2][1];
int spot9 = game_board[2][2];

printf("enter the number of the square you want to place an x in\n");
scanf("%d", );//what goes here?

printf("%d", game_board[row][col]);
printf("\n");`
```

This gives me the numbers 1-9 but I dont know the next step to change the value in the array. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: game_board[row][col] = value;

Answer (score 0):

Enter the position of the square? You just need to know the position of the square to put a x over that square.

```
#define CROSS -1
int i,j;
scanf("%d%d",&i,&j);
game_board[i][j]=CROSS;
```

So what should you do?

```
#define CROSS -1
int row1,col1;
printf("enter the position of the square you want to place an x in\n");
scanf("%d%d",&row1,&col1 );//what goes here?
// modify game_board[row1][col1] as you need. Assuming zero-indexing.
if(row1<3 && col1<3)
    game_board[row1][col1]=CROSS;
```

**Note**: Instead of hardcoding the `magic numbers` here 3, just use them as a macro. In this case it will be...

```
#define MAXROW 3
#define MAXCOL 3
```

These will help you change your code easily later.
You put checks like this ..

```
if(row<MAXROW && col <MAXCOL)
   // do something
```

The benefit is if you reconsider using a board size of 9x9 then you don't have to change all the 3's to 9's. Rather just change

```
#define MAXROW 9
#define MAXCOL 9
```

Comment: @isaac.: If this answer was useful accept or upvote it. As that's what make this post useful for future users.

Answer (score 0):

```
int r, c;

printf("enter the row number of the square you want to place an x in\n");
scanf("%d", &r);

printf("enter the column number of the square you want to place an x in\n");
scanf("%d", &c);

if (r <= row && c <= column)
    game_board[r][c] = 'x';
else
    /* error */
printf("%d\n", game_board[r][c]);
```